# Show that $|V(f)\cap C|\leq 2d$ for $C=\lbrace (x,y)\in \mathbb{C}^2\mid y=x^2\rbrace$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, polynomials

Let $d\in \mathbb{N}$  be the bound for the degree of  $f$ and $f(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{C}_{\leq d}[x_1,x_2]$.If $C=\lbrace (x,y)\in \mathbb{C}^2\mid y=x^2\rbrace$ is such that $C \not \subset V(f)$ then $|V(f)\cap C|\leq 2d$.
Where $V(f)$ denote the set of zeros of $f$

*Attempt*

I try a proof by contradiction, it is suppose that $|V(f)\cap C|> 2d$, and then use the fact that if a polynomial $f$ of degree $d$ is such that  $V(f)=\mathbb{C}^2$ then $f=0$.

Now I try fix $$f(x_1x_2)=\sum_{(i_1,i_2)}a_{i_1,i_2}x_1^{i_1}x_2^{i_2}$$ and now put $f$ in the form
$$f_a(x_2)=\sum_{i=0}^{e}r_i(a)x_2^{i}$$ for fixed $a\in \mathbb{C}$ and $e\leq d$.

I want show that for $(x,y)\in C$ if I take $y$ then $f_a(y)=0$ and since $V(f)\cap C\subset  C$ then $2d<|V(f)\cap C|\leq |C|$ then $f_a(x_2)$ must be the Zero polynomial and then $f=0$ and hence $f(c)=0\forall c\in C$ which means $C\subset V(f)$ and end the proof, but I don´t know how use $y=x^2$ to show $f_a(y)=0$ for each $y$.

Any hint was very useful.

Comment: An element of $C$ is $(x,x^2),$ for some $x.$ If it is also in $V(f),$ then $f(x,x^2)=0.$

Comment: is the degree of polynomial in two variables

Comment: put it in the question. Readers shouldn't need to read comments to get the full question.